# How do I get the input custom attribute from input in Python Splinter?

Tags: python, splinter

I have an input checkbox in a web page and I'm trying to retrieve the value number from this checkbox based on a custom attribute of this input.

Here is the input statement:

```
<input value="100047" name="DateAndTime_row_selector" alt="selectmultiplelines" title="selectmultiplelines" type="checkbox" onclick="icuesToggleTableRowSelection(this,'DateAndTime','null')" rftattr="MyDatetime">
```

So the string I'm looking for is "MyDatetime" which is the value of a custom attribute "rftattr". I will then need to return value "100047" so that I can click a link on another page that contains this number.

[This is the Datetime creation page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaTi8.png)

[This is rule creation page that selects this datetime.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcVcd.png)

How would I be able to achieve this please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the element by name or any other identifier, in this case for example, by name, and once you keep the element, you can retrive its attrs as a dict: element["attr1"]

Hope the nex code can help you

```
from splinter import Browser

page_to_visit = "http://www.somepage.com"

browser = Browser()

browser.visit(page_o_visit)

rftattr = browser.find_by_name("DateAndTime_row_selector").first["rftattr"]
# or  element = browser.find_by_name("DateAndTime_row_selector").first
# rftattr = element["rftattr"]
```